# Manga about two schoolgirls summoned to a magic world, they both fell down a stairway and isekaid

Tags: story-identification, manga

Finding a manga as per the title, read it on a manga site no older than 2013-2016 I really don't remember when I read it. Anyway it's about a plain black haired heroine and her beautiful classmate summoned to another world after falling down the stairs. The heroine is thought to have no powers due to her plain appearance and dismissed so she helps her friend fake her powers to use a magic sword. I don't remember the rest...

The heroine initially wears a school sailor uniform and knee length skirt, wears her black hair in a ponytail.

Edit: the genre is probably shoujo,fantasy and romance. There's definitely magic and romance included.

The manga site is probably mangakalot or mangago.

Design/artsyle is the typical black and white shoujo manga.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any ideas what manga sites you were reading back then?

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[+a no Tachiichi](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-no-tachiichi)*.

> Satoki Houma is an imaginative girl who enjoys shoujo manga. She has long comes to terms with the fact she will never be the type of girl that is the heroine of a manga — purely because she isn’t pretty, and she has decided she prefers to watch events unfold rather that get involved in any case. However, in the perfect shoujo manga twist, one day she gets **dragged to an alternate world** where the people have summoned a Holy Maiden to save them…! Except **so did her classmate**, Haruka Toudou, who fits the exact model of a Shoujo Protagonist. Naturally, Satoki is overlooked for Haruka… except it’s not Haruka who has the powers of the Holy Maiden they wished for. What will Satoki do!?

The first chapter includes a scene where the two girls are on a staircase that suddenly crumbles beneath them. They both fall down and end up in another world, with a handsome knight catching the friend and not the protagonist.

[image]

In the new world everyone assumes that the protagonist's friend is a holy maiden, ignoring the plain girl. The holy maiden has the ability to create weapons by manifesting her imagination. The summoners ask her to create a sword, but the friend is unable to do it. The protagonist thinks about the sword and it abruptly appears in front of her. Due to a misunderstanding it is assumed that the friend is the one that created it.

[image] [image]

Comment: Oh my god thank you. This forum is awesome.

Comment: @Madeline You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).